# How to transfer a PDF file to my picture album on my iPhone

Tags: iphone

I have an iPhone and when I was saving some pictures I saved them as PDF in iBooks. I want to transfer them to a picture album on my iPhone. Can I do it?

Answer (score 1):

No, it is not possible to transfer PDF files in picture album in iPhone to view in the Photos app.

You will either need to export the PDFs in an image format (PNG or JPG) to transfer in an album in Photos app, or you can sync and view them in iBooks app on your iPhone.